# Mysterious documents in internal storage -android

Tags: internal-storage, documents

Screenshot of space issue in Android. Some mysterious documents have taken lot of space. HOW DO I DELETE IT?

[image: Screenshot of storage settings]

Comment: IMHO ~1.87Mb is not a lot, the other part is it (but I guess it's the Android System itself).

Answer (score -1):

Nothing mysterious their it looks like app data and its common in all android mobiles

Comment: Thanks Mohan! I've already removed all unwanted files and this doesn't belong to app as apps data is in other category of 4.67 G. Moreover, android system has used up 5.54 G already.